# change default font on chinese locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass, locale, rails-i18n

im using 3 different locales in my application, spanish, english and chinese. The app uses .sass where i set the main font like the following:

```
$main-font: "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Microsoft_YaHei247019", "Verdana"
```

This way $main-font would use first "Whitney SSm A", if this font family does not have the required character it will search on "Whitney SSm B" fonts, then "Microsoft_YaHei247019" and last "Verdana".

The problem is i would like to change this order when the language is chinese, setting "Microsoft_YaHei247019" as default. It should be:

```
$main-font: "Microsoft_YaHei247019", "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Verdana"
```

But only when language is chinese.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use CSS to target a language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973061/use-css-to-target-a-language)

Comment: Depending on your version of windows if its English or Chinese you need to specify both values:

font-family: Arial, "Microsoft Yahei","微软雅黑", STXihei, "华文细黑", sans-serif;

http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/

Answer (score 3):

I would set a CSS class on the body tag to hold the current locale:

```
<body class="<%= I18n.locale %>">

</body>
```

And then you can target that class in your SASS:

```
body.en
  $main-font: "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Microsoft_YaHei247019", "Verdana"

body.cn
  $main-font: "Microsoft_YaHei247019", "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Verdana"
```

Comment: was a good idea @infused, but for some reason i get "Microsoft_YaHei247019" for every language this way